# How do I adhere to the limit of requests in Google Maps API?

Tags: java, google-maps, caching

I am using the Google Maps Directions API and some other ones(https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java). 
They have a limit of 2500 requests / day : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#Limits

I know that I should cache the responses. However, if I am using those services APIs, how can I cache it? Should I have to do manual Java HTTP requests only to cache the responses? Or are there any ways to cache even if I use those service APIs?

Comment: You should check out the docs here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/articles/usage_limits#cache

Comment: Yeah! As I said I understand that I should cache the responses but in the APIs, is there any way to instruct that?